# How to detect and display desired message when clicked on DefaultMutableTreeNode in java?

Tags: java

I am tryin to make a software in which when clicked on the subnode of a jtree, detecting which node is selected, want to display respective message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a [TreeSelectionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeSelectionListener.html) to the model containing your nodes.  The event arguments contain data for the node(s) selected.
  Here is some [example documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#select).